# Nginx seems to ignore server_name when ssl and http2 is on

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have this nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    client_max_body_size 5G;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```

So `http://www.example.com` is redirected to `https://www.example.com`. Problem is, that `https://example.com` also works and serves proxy pass to port `8888`. How can I prevent it to work? I need just version with www to be working. Parameter server_name does not seem to have any effect. I am using "nginx version: nginx/1.10.1".

Comment: I ultimately fixed this by adding explicit redirect for version without www, but still curious why I needed to do that and version without www proxy passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you explicitly define a default server for port 443, `nginx` will use the first matching `server` block to process the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for details.

The solution is to explicitly define a default server with the desired behaviour, for example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

In fact, you could probably roll it into your port 80 `server` block, if you delete the `server_name` directive:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
    client_max_body_size 5G;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8888;
    }
}
```