# nginx returns SSL certificate for subdomain that should have no certificate

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, configuration, server

I have a nginx server that manages a few domains and subdomains. There are some subdomains that have an own SSL certificate and they work fine. The problem is that if I try to open blablabla.mydomain.com (this subdomain is not configured in nginx) then firefox shows me an error "Connection is not secure" and "The certificate is only valid for xyz.mydomain.com" (this domain is configured with SSL and works well)

The same happens when I open the root domain mydomain.com. Then the server also returns the certificate for xyz.mydomain.com which is rejected by firefox.

I only want nginx to return the SSL certificate for domains/subdomains I explicitly have configured HTTPS. For what I understand, my configuration should be doing exactly this.

I configured all my https-subdomains like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xyz.mydomain.com;
    root /var/www/xyz.mydomain/;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xyz.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    ...
}
```

The root domain (which should have no SSL) is configured like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return http://some-redirection.com;
}
```

There is no SSL server block for this domain. Nor is for the other subdomains that do not exist. So why does nginx in these cases return the certificate for xyz.mydomain.com?

I don't use any wildcards in my server config. Is there some way to debug this? I mean, there must be a reason why nginx always returns the certificate for xyz.mydomain.com for every non-configured domain/subdomain. Why not another configured and working certificate?

I use an Ubuntu 14.04 server with nginx 1.4.6

If you need more info on my config, let me know

EDIT: I think I know why my config does not work. When using https the client encrypts also the domain name and this causes nginx to try all available server defintions. When it doesn't find one it returns the last one? And xyz.mydomain.com seems to be the last one (alphabetically)

So is there a way to avoid this? Would I have to create a ssl cert for every other subdomain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx seems to ignore server\_name when ssl and http2 is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40107732/nginx-seems-to-ignore-server-name-when-ssl-and-http2-is-on)

Comment: check that your domain is not defined here: https://www.chromium.org/hsts or using `HSTS`